# Impact of MUI v5's sx={{...}} props on React App Performance?

Tags: reactjs, performance, material-ui, styled-components, emotion

I am utilizing Material UI's "sx={{ }}" props to style the components of my React application, which has resulted in a large number of style elements being added to the head section. As my application is a dashboard that will integrate with numerous RESTful APIs, it is already quite sizable. I am concerned about the potential impact of these style elements on the performance of my application as it grows. Can anyone advise me on whether this is likely to cause issues?

[image: my code]

[image: what I see in browser]

[image: what I see in browser]

Is it typical for Material UI to generate a large number of  elements when styling components in a React application?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11286032)